# Appearing two splash screen

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I configured the splash screen and two are showing.

How do I remove it first?

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@color/primary" />
      <item
        android:drawable="@mipmap/logo"
        android:height="300dp"
        android:width="300dp"
        android:gravity="center"
      />
    </layer-list>
```

This is my splash screen and before she appears another one with the ic_launcher_round.